# use of 14hive resources in XSLT for XLV

Tags: 2010, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part, resource-files

Is there a way to use 14hive(**!**) custom resources ( *Resource:MyCompany.MyProject.resx, MyProject.SomeComponent.SomeResourceKey;* ) in a XSLT files for *XsltListViewWebPart* (and views)? Please, notice the **dot separator** in resx filename and key values.
I have read what [Andrey described for GlobalApp resources](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/3-ways-to-localize-SharePoint-XSLT.aspx). Tried *Core.resx* resources works for me:

```
view.ParameterBindings = 
@"<ParameterBinding Name=""TCMessage"" Location=""Resource(core,Tasks_Completed)"" />";
```

but, not customized resources:

```
view.ParameterBindings = 
@"<ParameterBinding Name=""TCMessage"" Location=""Resource(MyCompany.MyProject,Tasks.Completed)"" />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the following format, you are pretty close.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Resources.resourceFile.ResourceName" />
```

is

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Resources.custom.custome_resource" />
```

will get custom.wss and custom_resource inside it.

Comment: I have a naming rule in the company to use "." as separator in the resx file names and resx keys. Its the same way Andrey described in the entry (2 way).

Comment: You shouldn't use periods in file names, they are for file descriptor separators only. SharePoint doesn't support the use of multiple periods at all. SharePoint, ProFTP, TransferText, Symphony, KVR Audio and servedir all do not support multiple periods in file names.

Comment: What is the other issues with filenames containing periods in SharePoint?

Comment: Sharepoint uses almost the same file format recognising method throughout since early on frontpage portal. This is basically checking the file extension and splitting with periods. Any hive file with periods when SharePoint attempts to recognise the file type could fail because of this. It works fine with libraries because the files are checked by mime type, however say you work with the RPC functions to upload files these fail as they depend on file extensions.